# words match separately with LIKE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Does anyone have a LIKE pattern that matches below situation?

```
ID| NAMES
1 | CHAN TAI MAN
2 | CHAN SIO LONG LEI TAI MAN
3 | LEI CHAN TAI MAN
```

=====================

I'm using SqlServer2008, and I need to search "LEI TAI MAN", then my expected result:

```
2 | CHAN SIO LONG LEI TAI MAN
3 | LEI CHAN TAI MAN
```

Comment: `%LEI%TAI%MAN%`

Comment: Dale Burrell's will certainly work. If the words were not always in the same order, ie `MAN LEI TAI`, you could do `Names LIKE '%LEI%' AND Names LIKE '%TAI%' AND Names LIKE '%MAN%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
Select * from tablename
where  NAMES like '%LEI%'
   AND NAMES like '%TAI%'
   AND NAMES like '%MAN%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=335d07669e66d98ef34ed1fb350af0e8)**

```
select * from tablename
where NAMES like %LEI%TAI%MAN%
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  names
2   CHAN SIO LONG LEI TAI MAN
3   LEI CHAN TAI MAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Making Much complexity for `LIKE` operator

You can try this way

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE NAMES LIKE '%'+ REPLACE('LEI TAI MAN',' ','%') + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

**This could be the best solution for your question.**

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table name> WHERE <column name> LIKE '%LEI% %TAI% %MAN%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern could exist in any order, you could use the above option of something similar to:

```
WHERE Value LIKE '%LEI%'
    AND Value LIKE '%MAN%'
    AND Value LIKE '%TAI%'
```

or you could do something like below to keep the pattern stored in a table variable.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Value NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Data
(Value)
VALUES
('CHAN TAI MAN'),
('CHAN SIO LONG LEI TAI MAN'),
('LEI CHAN TAI MAN');

DECLARE @Patterns TABLE (
    Pattern NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED (Pattern)
);

INSERT INTO @Patterns
(Pattern)
VALUES
('LEI'),
('TAI'),
('MAN');

DECLARE @PatternCount INT;

SET @PatternCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @Patterns);

SELECT *
FROM @Data AS d
WHERE @PatternCount = (
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM @Patterns AS p
    WHERE d.Value LIKE CONCAT('%',p.Pattern,'%')
    );
```

By doing the 2nd option, you could pass in a string of options as comma separated, use a function to normalize it into an array that you can insert into the table variable, and do what I listed. Lots of fun options...

Something like this could also allow you to create a threshold. Something like it must match at least 60%.